# Kendo MVVM - Bind to ENTIRE View Model

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I have a situation where I am wanting to observe the behavior of a view model as I am populating a form. I can do this with defining a lot of fields that look kind of like the model, and binding to them, but that is kind of messy.

I am currently accomplishing this with the following code;

```
(function ($) {
    $.printJSON = function(value){
        return JSON.stringify(value, undefined, 2);
    }
})(jQuery);

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
                    // other fields etc
    update: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#json_result").html($.printJSON(this));
    }
});


<div style="width: 400px; float: left; padding-left: 15px;" >
    <button data-bind="click: update" value="Update" >Update</button>
    <pre id="json_result">
    </pre>
</div>
```

So you click the button, and it runs the function to draw the view model JSON to the screen, all nice and formatted.

But this still requires a button click. While that isn't that big of a problem for me, since this isn't something I need for a lot of situations, is there any way to actually do this and have it update when the view model changes in any way? I tried to just bind to the function and it never updates without an explicit call, I tried binding right to the view model, and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You could either simply bind the [change](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/observableobject#events-change) event:

```
viewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
    $("#json_result").html($.printJSON(this));
});
```

or you could use a calculated field:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    field1: "field1",
    field2: "field2",
    field3: "field3",
    print: function () {
        // need to register for all fields so that the change event for print is triggered
        for (var fieldName in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
                this.get(fieldName);
            }
        }

        return $.printJSON(this.toJSON());
    }
});
```

and bind to it with:

```
<pre data-bind="html: print">
```

See fiddle demonstrating both methods: http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/S2WeB/